# What is known about functions of type $f(n+1) = f(n)^ {f(n)}$?

Tags: soft-question, functional-equations, recreational-mathematics

Update : having looked at [Knut's Double Arrow Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) ( Thank you DJC), it seems that this question is nothing more than a frivourless wondering that should be undertaken by whom ever wonders it, it is an example of type of questions that are easy to ask but seem to have no defined way of being answered or having a systematic use in mathematics, I have voted for it to close (if that is the correct thing todo in this situation).

$f(n+1) = \left(f(n)\right)^ {f(n)} , f(1)=2$
e.g. $f(2)=2^2 , f(3)=\left({2^2}\right)^{2^2},f(4)={\left({2^2}\right)^{2^2}}^{\left({2^2}\right)^{2^2}} $, 
ok it just another fast growing function, but it looks too simple that makes one wonder if there is an analytic version for it exists? e.g. what can be said about the $f(2.5)$ or $f(1+i)$ or it's inverse function or it's derivative, taylor series? of course even any result as relating to something as simple as $f(n+\frac{1}{2})$ seems intresting.

Edit : just looking for any known results for such a simple looking construction, tx

Comment: Is this a question, or a fishing expedition?

Comment: @Gerry, tried to tidy it up as much as I could.

Comment: What's a fishing expedition?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation

Comment: http://www.tetration.org/  ...  http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/index.php   ...  please discuss it there, not here ...

Comment: @a little don, see http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fishing+expedition

Comment: @Gerry : Yes, this seems to be a total fishing expedition.

Comment: J.E. Littlewood introduced analogue of the "double arrow" even earlier than Knuth, at 1948 and it is reprinted in a chapter "large numbers" in his "A Mathematician's Miscellany". He even used some idea about numbers like $N_{2.47}$. It is here http://www.archive.org/details/mathematiciansmi033496mbp page 100.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(n)=a^{g(n)}$ , where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $a\neq1$ ,

Then $a^{g(n+1)}=(a^{g(n)})^{a^{g(n)}}$

$a^{g(n+1)}=a^{g(n)a^{g(n)}}$

$g(n+1)=g(n)a^{g(n)}$

Let $g(n)=a^{h(n)}$ , where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $a\neq1$ ,

Then $a^{h(n+1)}=a^{h(n)}a^{a^{h(n)}}$

$a^{h(n+1)}=a^{h(n)+a^{h(n)}}$

$h(n+1)=h(n)+a^{h(n)}$

which the solution is more complicated than the iterated exponentials.